# How to adjust empty cv::Mat object

Tags: c++, opencv

I understand how to create a opencv Mat object supposed the pointer to the image pixels as well as some other auxiliary information is given. For example:

```
int width = 100;
int height = 200;
unsigned char *pPixel = new unsigned char [width*height];
cv::Mat myMat(height,width, CV_8UC1,pPixel);
delete []nPixel;
```

My next question is: suppose myMat already exists as an empty cv::Mat object, and in this case how can we assign image information to the empty myMat object? This can happen in the following function:

```
void create_mat(int width, int height, int band_num, unsigned char *pPixel, cv::Mat &obj)
{
   // adjust obj based on width, height and pPixel

}
```

EDIT:Possible solutions:

```
 void create_mat(int width, int height, int band_num, unsigned char *pPixel, cv::Mat &obj)
    {
        obj.data = pPixel;
        obj.rows = height;
        obj.cols = width;
           // how to assign image data type?

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `band_num` means, bu you could use

```
void create_mat(int width, int height, int band_num, unsigned char *pPixel, cv::Mat &obj)
{
   obj.create(width, height, type); // e.g. type: CV_8UC1
   obj.data = pPixel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To assign data to an already initialized Mat object ,you can use `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(pPixel, pPixel + width*height, &obj.data[0]);
```

and if that matrix is already initialized with:

cv::Mat myMat(height,width, CV_8UC1);

You do not need any further modification to set data type.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is two folds: 1) I do not want the cv::Mat object take control of the memory and 2)　I　do not know how to assign the image type information to this object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same constructor:

```
void create_mat(int width, int height, int band_num, unsigned char *pPixel, cv::Mat &obj)
{
    obj = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1, pPixel);
}
```